# Bash always outputs to less, how can I turn this off?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, less, pager

After a recent update `bash` seems to always output to `less`, which is resulting in pagination for many commands. Does anyone know how to turn `less` off?

Example output for `systemctl status`

[image: Output of systemctl status]

Comment: It's not bash that's doing it. Is it only systemctl 's behavior that changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The man page for `systemctl` (`man systemctl`) explains this behaviour clearly, and offers options to change it:

> `$SYSTEMD_PAGER` Pager to use when `--no-pager` is not given; overrides `$PAGER`. If neither `$SYSTEMD_PAGER` nor `$PAGER` are set, a set of well-known pager implementations are tried in turn, including `less`(1) and `more`(1), until one is found. If no pager implementation is discovered no pager is invoked. Setting this environment variable to an empty string or the value "`cat`" is equivalent to passing `--no-pager`.

So in your case the solution is to set the environment variable when you log in:

```
export SYSTEMD_PAGER=cat
```

Answer (score 4):

More widely, you can define PAGER environment in your bash runtime config

```
# In .bashrc or .bash_profile

export PAGER='cat'
```

Answer (score 2):

I often log into a system where it's a bad idea to change `~/root/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, etc. And I don't always remember the parameter name `SYSTEMD_PAGER`.

So, as a lazy hack I simply pipe the output through `cat` or `less` (my preferred pager), like so:

```
systemctl status | cat
systemctl status | less
```

This trick for `cat` works for many other programs as well. For example, if I don't want to deal with how `info` navigates it's pages, I simply do this:

`info bash | less`

Comment: Is there a way to make the content of `--help` always be piped to `less` automatically, without me piping it to `less`? E.g. I want `dpkg --help` to be interpreted as `dpkg --help | less` automatically. Same for all `--help` commands.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ No I don't think there is a built in way. For this to work, every program would need to build in support for this (Or support the `PAGER` environment parameter), and unfortunately they don't. Using `dpkg --help | less` is the best method that I know of.